# Convergence of an Integral series of Trig Function.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

$$\int^{+\infty}_{1}\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^2dx$$

I just have to show in a simple comparison with a known derivative if this function converges. My guess is to substitute $1/x$ for $u$ and then integrate $\tan(u)$.

If this converges then the above function also converges. What if the question is like

$$\sum_{n=17}^{\infty}\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^2 \ \ ?$$

Will the same argument work or do I have to use another one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After substitution, $u=1/x$, you get
$$
\int_0^1\Bigl(\frac{\tan u}{u}\Bigr)^2\,du.
$$
Now, $\frac{\tan u}{u}\to 1$ as $u\to 0$, so the integrand is bounded (here we also use that $1<\pi/2$ which is the first positive singularity of the tangent function), and so the integral converges.

Thanks to the limit above there exists $C>0$ so that
$$
\tan(1/x)\leq C/x,
$$
for $x>1$. Therefore
$$
\bigl(\tan(1/n)\bigr)^2\leq C^2/n^2.
$$
I leave it to you to conclude.

Comment: isn't a minus sign missing in the substitution part?

Comment: No. The first integral is clearly positive, so that must hold for the one after the substitution as well.

Comment: And the bounds have been switched.

Comment: ok i get it now. The upper limit is now smaller than the lower so we switch the signs? but what i also dont get is, how did you conclude it without solving the integral ? that just amazes me sorry im just a beginner.

Comment: For a bounded continuous function on a bounded interval there is no problem of convergence. We don't need to know  the value of the integral to know that it is finite.

Comment: @SherlockHomies. The question is : *does the integral converge ?* No more.

Comment: @mickep i am sorry but i still dont understand what happens to the upper limit of 1 ? and how you concluded so till then i can't accept it as an answer.

Comment: Nothing really happens at $1$. The tangent function is continuous on $[0,1]$, and hence bounded there. It is not defined at $\pi/2$, but that is not a problem here, since $\pi/2>1$.